# Easy!Appointments Full Calender version bug

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using **Easy Appointment** updated version where **Full Calendar** Version is v1.6.1. But **Full Calendar** updated version is : v3.1.0

**Easy appointment** uses **full calendar** version v1.6.1, which has a time selection bug. 
below the link for reference:
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2945

```
This is latest example of Full Calendar where time slot click is working fine:
```

`http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/y8ugsvnL/`

Is there are any updated version where Easy Appointment is using latest Full Calendar? or any alternate suggestion?

Comment: According to the Easy appointments releases, Easy!Appointments v1.2.0
@alextselegidis alextselegidis released this on Nov 10, 2016 includes an update for FullCalendar - better update yours too?

Comment: @Mikkel, At updated Easy Appointment v1.2.0, they are still using back dated Full calendar v1.6.1. 
Full Calendar directory :
/easyappointments_1.2.0/assets/ext/jquery-fullcalendar/jquery.fullcalendar.min.js

Comment: That seems silly! You could do one of 1) Raise an issue with them 2) Fork the repo and make the change yourself, submit a PR and/or publish the package under a different name (and then use this new one)

Comment: I gauge, latest version of Full Calendar might not be compatible with Easy Appointments. From Code Diff I see that, 97% of Code of Full Calendar  has been updated / modified.